# I want to create a automatic partition on the table in mysql for one of the column

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql database and i want to create a partition on the table based on distinct values of the columns.
lets say the column name is state since there can be multiple value in the state i don't want to define the partitions while creating the table.
i want that the partition to be create automatically based on distinct state value in MySQL

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: hi
the scenario is i work for telecom industry. i have a use case where i am saving the information regarding the cells (telecom term)  (refer here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_network) belonging to particular circles (here circle is different states of country) 
in India there can be 29 distinct circles so my data for all the circles is more than 20M and fetching the data from the table is taking much time. i have all the primary key enabled then also data fetching is time consuming.
so i think if i create partitions based on circles the fetching would be faster

Comment: Partition cannot be created implicitly. Check and create additional partitions if needed from service event procedure.

Comment: Does manual partitioning make any difference? If not, automatic partitioning won't make any difference either.